# No launcher and menus in Ubuntu 12.10 after changing from Nvidia to Intel Graphics

Tags: unity, drivers, nvidia, intel

I have removed my discrete Nvidia GPU from my PC and I was planing to use my internal Intel HD 2500 instead.  But it does not work properly. Since then I am missing my Unity launcher and the top menu. I have tried to reinstall several stuff and purged the nvidia-driver, but nothing helped so far.

If you need further information just mention it.

I am glad for every help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at his:-

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2093940

specifically for yourself down the bottom, where there is:-

Luckily if you find yourself in the same situation as me, you can very easily revert to the standard Open Source driver [ATI/Radeon] as follows:-
Get the System Settings screen after clicking the top right settings icon.
Select Software Sources and Additional Drivers tab.
Select the AMD/ATI dispaly driver wrapper option and Apply Changes
Logout and back in again

Good luck pardner!